# Deep Learning sentiment analysis model always predicts same class

Tags: deep-learning, natural-language, word-embeddings, sentiment-analysis

I'd really appreciate your help as I'm not an expert in Deep Learning for sentiment analysis and I'm a bit lost. 
I'm using the Sentiment140 dataset: http://help.sentiment140.com/for-students

First I've created my own word embeddings using the train dataset and gensim library, then I built a model in Keras. 
The val accuracy is low (0.5) and when I try to use the model to predict new sentences it's always predicting class 'neutral' no matter what sentence is.

The code is on github: 
word2vec: https://github.com/zarkhaari/sentiment-analysis-dl/blob/master/sentiment140_word2vec.ipynb

model: https://github.com/zarkhaari/sentiment-analysis-dl/blob/master/sentiment140_cnn_saved_w2c.ipynb

It would be great if you could tell if you spot any evident mistake that is causing the low accuracy.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: From the look of it, your training accuracy keeps increasing and your val accuracy and loss are stable (0.5 is random assuming the classes negative and positive have the same proportions) and cannot really get worse as it is already random guess. My first diagnostic would be to have a lower learning rate and some dropout to see the training accuracy increase slower.

Comment: How is your test LOSS behaving.  You may simply be using a poor threshold for classification.

Comment: @MatthewDrury the model predicts the probability for each class and the second class(=neutral) is always the one with the highest probability, no matter what the sentence is. 
For example : "I really love this, it's fantastic"  [0,2. 0.8, 0]

Comment: I think what Matthew is saying is that due to possible class imbalance you might want to have a higher threshold (i.e, to be classified as neutral you want the prediction to be some threshold higher than 0.5).

Comment: Yup, Tom's got it.  If your population just HAS much more neutrals, then it's not surprising that that marginal probability has an outsized effect on the conditional probability coming out of your model.  If you want to develop a rule that classifies less records as neutral, you will need to scale down the amount of evidence you need to classify something as non-neutral.

Comment: thank you both, I thought you always have to use argmax to select the predicted class. The thing I found odd is that no matter what text I use the probabilities look very similar: first class around 0.2, second 0.8 and 3rd is close to 0

Comment: I found a mistake in my implementation. When testing new texts I was creating a new keras Tokenizer instead of the one trained on the corpus. I think the solution is to save the tokenizer when training the model and then load and use it when predicting classes for new texts.